# Issue using GEKKO solve in Python: getting different result using same code in two different .py files

Tags: python, pandas, gekko

The libraries used are pandas to read an excel file and gekko to solve an equation.
Both .py files use the same code and the same excel file.
The difference between them is one has an extra for cycle to get values from several sheets and the other is only able to read one sheet at a time.

The results they produce from the same sheet are different.
Shouldn't they be the same since the data is equal?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Please post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. Otherwise, it is difficult to provide specific suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Gekko uses solvers that iterate to find a solution. However, the same outputs can be expected with the same inputs and equations. Here is an example that returns `True` and `True` to verify that the solutions are the same.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m1 = GEKKO()
x1,y1 = m1.Array(m1.Var,2)
m1.Equations([3*x1+2*y1==1, x1+2*y1==0])
m1.solve(disp=False)

m2 = GEKKO()
x2,y2 = m2.Array(m2.Var,2)
m2.Equations([3*x2+2*y2==1, x2+2*y2==0])
m2.solve(disp=False)

print(x1.value[0]==x2.value[0])
print(y1.value[0]==y2.value[0])
```